# After Update from 14.04 to 16.04 all the menus disappeared

Tags: 14.04, unity, 16.04, updates, taskbar

I updated today from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 via the official client. I did everything as recommended and let it remove the outdated packages in the end. After the first restart it said that there has been an "internal error" and I had no Unity menu nor a taskbar or anything similar. The only way for me to open Firefox was by opening a picture with Firefox that I had on my desktop. I cant minimize or close the window with my mouse, only with Alt+F4.

So if someone would tell me what to do, I'd be very grateful

Greeting

Vitus

Comment: Oh, I forgot, pressing the Windows Button does nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try restarting unity?

#### Try:

- In terminal run: "sudo service lightdm restart"

  If that that didn't work, in terminal run:
- "unity"